# Rails dynamic routes with url helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Say I have a routes setup like this

```
scope"(foo/:user_id/)" do
  resources :bar
end
```

Can I still use URL helper methods to generat my URLs (without having to write my own)?

What would the url helper method look like to get the url /foo/1234/bar/new

Answer (score 0):

Try using, for example, `bar_path(:user_id => 1, :id => 2)` to get `/foo/1/bar/2`.

Btw, why do you need these parenthesis in the scope? I think it should be just like that:

```
scope "foo/:user_id/" do
  resources :bar
end
```

Shouldn't it?

Comment: Gives a `undefined method 'bar_path' for #<#<Class:0x1796c1a02>:0xdc647fe>`

Comment: Where are you calling `bar_path` helper when you get that error? Can you share output from `rake routes`?